# About transition effect on Unveil jquery plugin (lazyLoad)

Tags: jquery, css, lazy-loading

I have a small doubt I hope someone can help me out with.

I'm using Unveil (by Luis Almeida) jquery plugin to lazy load images. It is quite easy to implement and everything work as expected (more or less). However, according documentation, there is way to apply a cool ease-in transition with CSS when the image has been loaded (or at least that's what I've understood).

The HTML looks like this

```
<div class="col-xs-12 workImage">
        <img src="images/spinner.gif" data-src="pictures/pic3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
</div>
```

I have this code

```
$(function() {
        $('.workImage').find('img').unveil(-300, function() {
            $(this).css( { 'opacity': 1} );
        });
});
```

and this CSS

```
.workImage img{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
```

The problem is that with this code, the effect is applied to the whole `<img>` tag, spinner included and not **only** to the image we want to reveal once is loaded. Not sure if you know what I mean.

When I go to the page, unveil applies the effect and the spinner is shown with that cool CSS effect and starts to *spin* until the picture is loaded, when that happens it just fires the image but without any effect (because that happened to the `<img>` tag).

Documentation says you can specify a callback function that will fire after an image has been "unveiled". And I'm not sure if I'm not using this properly. Can anyone gimme a hand with this?

Here is the Unveil webpage where you can read the usage and documentation:

http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If there a reason you are using -300 rather than a positive number for the unveil position parameter?

Comment: @thisiskelvin thanks for reply. I think I haven't explained myself clear enough. Your code doesn't really do anything different from what I had. You can see an example here http://tanaanstudio.com/testDipesh2/ Please keep in mind this: Thumbs are loaded using lazyLoad, NOT unveil. You must click on any of the first four thumbs, some content will be expanded and it is on the images in there where Unveil is used. Landscapes images are the heaviest where you can easily see what I'm trying to say. You will notice the spinner is fade in but not the image once is loaded. Many thanks

Comment: @thisiskelvin threshold to -300 is just to load the images when I scroll down 300px below where the image I want to unveil is. This is just to make everything easier to see.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. So I see the spiral notebook fade in. The problem was that you are seeing both the spinner and the image?

Comment: @thisiskelvin no. The problem is that I don't want to apply the effect to the spinner but the image when is loaded. Forgot about the greyscale images because they are not too heavy and loading time is not enough to see how everything works. Focus on the Landscapes images, at the bottom of the content. If you open any of the first four thumbs and you scroll down you will find a Landscape image and you'll notice how the spinner is fade in but not the image.

Comment: I see what you mean, Although the large landscape images load fine on my screen (maybe because of net speed), on the plugin website, some of the images did not load quickly, and the "no image" icon came up but the spinner was visible. I've seen some people had issues and moved to https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload

Comment: @thisiskelvin Not sure what you mean when you say a 8mb image loads fine (you probably already load them earlier and now they are cached). images on Unveil website are not loaded properly because of a lorempixel issue I guess, this is not important at all with the issue, plus he is not using the ease-in effect to reveal the images. The link you post is about lazyLoad, we are mixing concepts here. Thanks anyway for your time, mate. I will post the solution if I can solve it.